# Coalesce columns in spark java dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark

There are similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109064/coalesce-duplicate-columns-in-spark-dataframe) on Stack Overflow for the same question but none on a Java Spark Dataframe.

Can anyone help me with the same but in java.

I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109064/coalesce-duplicate-columns-in-spark-dataframe) but its not working on Java. Seems like coalesce function takes `Scala.collections.seq<columns>`  as type. how to make it work in Java

Comment: you always may write it in sql way.

Comment: Doing it sql way  is fine. but I would like to make it work on dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to convert the columns to Seq to make it work in Java 8.

```
public Seq<Column> getSeqString(Column a, Column b)
    {
        ArrayList<Column> cols = new ArrayList<Column>();
        cols.add(a);
        cols.add(b);
        return scala.collection.JavaConverters.collectionAsScalaIterableConverter(cols).asScala().toBuffer();
    }
```